# Conditional statement based on CSS width percentage property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, conditional-statements

I’m trying to set up a conditional statement based on width percentage of CSS property. It’s very simple, if the width percentage of a certain class is something, then something happens. But my code isn’t working. I’m well aware that width in percentage needs to be calculated in jQuery and that’s exactly what I did. Can someone help?

My sample:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $.fn.widthPerc = function() {
    return ~~(($('.percent').width() / $('.progress-bar').width()) * 100) + "%";
  }
  function skillLevel() {
    if ($('.percent')..widthPerc() <= "65%") {
      $('.percent').text('Skilled')
    }
    else if ($('.percent').widthPerc() >= "90%") {
      $('.percent').text('Master')
    }
  }
  $('.P-S-skill3').hover(toggleEdge);
});

function toggleEdge() {
  $('.percent').css('width', '65%');
}
```

Comment: Why are there two dots in `$('.percent')..widthPerc()`?

Comment: lol..sorry it should be one..but even with that, still not working..any suggestions?